# What are the reasons to use erb integration for webpacker in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, webpacker

I have surfed a couple of hours through the web but couldn't find any articles/walkthroughs/comparisons touching **erb integration of webpacker**. I've found 1 question, unfortunately, the author haven't read docs attentively and the answer was right there, so - no any additional info there.

I have seen plenty of articles about vue and react, but nobody says a word about erb. However, it's quite clear why using react/vue/else similiar, it is not with erb.

The theme is quite vast and I expect a little hate towards me, so I'd ask two related questions (*but if you have something to tell more about it - that's appreciated*).

As I understand - it's vanilla (plain) js (maybe with a flavour of jQuery) caring just about dom and styling, with all the preprocessing made by rails. If it is so why not just continue using sprockets?

And what are the reasons to choose it instead of some react/vue/else framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use both : a vanilla JS framework (React, Vue ...) and some erb files. I find it interesting to setup my constant and other configuration variables within a .js.erb file that is generated by my Rails app when building the js app.

Things I like to put in this erb files :

- schemas of my api, generated by my serializers
- constants, like enum
  values to be used in forms

To generalize, you can put anything owned by the backend that will not change at run time

this save you a couple API calls to retrieve this data. However, I tend to stop doing this as your JS app and Rails become tightly coupled and you can't use the sources of your JS app outside the Rails app